# Understanding a statement in a probability journal paper

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading inequality (5.2) on page 28 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08564.pdf) and I am trying to understand the meaning of the event $\{\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\in \widehat{B}\}$. In terms of notation, I don't think any information other than that $\widetilde{\xi}_\ell$ is a random variable, and the definition of $\widehat{B}$, is required:
$$\widehat{B}:=\{e\in \widetilde{S}_\ell: \mathbb{P}(\xi_\ell=e|T)\leq \frac{1}{n}\exp(\Gamma\sqrt{\log n})\}.$$

> My question is whether $\mathbb{P}(\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\in \widehat{B})$ is equal to (1) or (2):
>
> 1. $\mathbb{P}\left(\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\in \widetilde{S}_\ell, \mathbb{P}(\xi_\ell=\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\mid T)\leq \frac{1}{n}\exp\left(\Gamma\sqrt{\log n}\right)\right)$
> 2. $\mathbb{P}\left(\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\in \widetilde{S}_\ell, \mathbb{P}(\xi_\ell=\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\mid \widetilde{\xi}_\ell,T)\leq \frac{1}{n}\exp\left(\Gamma\sqrt{\log n}\right)\right)$

Appreciate your response.

Comment: I don't know if you automatically get notified if an answer is edited, but I added a note that (1) is also a bad way to write it because of a confusion about what is and isn't a random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the answer is (1). The way you phrase (2) makes it seem like the value of the random variable $\widetilde{\xi}_{\ell}$ might affect the probability $\mathbb{P}(\xi_\ell=e|T)$. However, $\widehat{B}$ does not account for any such change in the probability, so we also shouldn't consider that. Maybe given that $\widetilde{\xi}_\ell = e$ for some particular $e$, it is always the case that $\xi_{\ell}=e$. Nevertheless, $\widehat{B}$ could still include $e$ because the probability of $\xi_{\ell} = e$ is too small. That probability inside the definition of $\widehat{B}$ is only a function of the marginal of the space on $\xi_\ell$ and $T$.

But there is a problem you have to be careful of with this rephrasing. In the expression (1), $\widetilde{\xi}_{\ell}$ is no longer a random variable, it is just an element of $\widetilde{S}$. This is extremely confusing, so a better way to write the probability should just be $\mathbb{P}(\widetilde{\xi}_{\ell} \in \widehat{B})$, I don't know if there's an even better way to say it.

To see why this warning is so important and confusing, take a simpler example. Consider you roll an unbalanced die where each even outcome has a 1/4 chance, and each odd a 1/12 chance of appearing. You have two random variables $A$, $B$, and you store the outcome of the roll in both of them. Now consider the set $S = \{e \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} : \mathbb{P}(A = e) < 1/6\}$. What is the probability that $B \in S$? The answer should be 1/4, but if you substitute $B$ for $e$ like you did in (1) or (2), you get $\mathbb{P}(B \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} : \mathbb{P}(A = B) < 1/6)$. If $B$ is just ranging over the outcomes in this expression, we get $1/4$. However, if we forget this and actually calculate $\mathbb{P}(A = B) < 1/6$ in a more intuitive way, we get that this condition is always false and so we'd think the probability would be 0.

Comment: Thanks for an updated answer. This was precisely my concern. I think you are right that I should just say $\mathbb{P}(\widetilde{\xi}_\ell\in \widehat{B})$. In your example, may I know why $P(B\in S)=1/4$? It's a good example, and I am not sure how to find $P(B\in S)$. Does $B$ stand for the roll being odd? Are $A,B$ independent random variables? Thanks.

Comment: @trickymaverick $A$ and $B$ are the outcome of one die roll. So their distribution is the same as the distribution of the unbalanced die. Hence $S$ is just the odd outcomes. Because of that, $B \in S$ happens with probability $1/4$. And no, $A$ and $B$ are not independent. $B$ is just a copy of $A$, so they're always equal.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! It makes sense now.